# XSD that allows any combination of two elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have huge XML files, and all have only 2 element types. But, the hierarchy of the elements keeps changing per xml. Is it possible to create an XSD with 2 element types and all elements of the XML documents will validate against this XSD?

E.g.

Lets say `a` and `b` are the only possible element types

1.xml

```
<b attr1="hello">
    <b attr1="Hello">
       <a></a>
       <a></a>
    </b>
    <a></a>
</b>
```

2.xml

```
<b attr1="hello">
    <b attr1="hello">
       <a></a>
       <a></a>
       <b attr1="hello">
           <a></a>
       </b>
    </b>
    <a></a>

</b>
```

Can I validate both XML documents with same XSD which defines how element `a` and `b` should look?

**Update**: Added attributes to 'b' node.

Comment: If there is a rule that applies to all the documents you can define it with xsd. If there is no rule then there is also nothing to define. (In any schema language)

Comment: Rule is only two element types are possible in all the xmls. But hierarchy keeps changing

Comment: Ok, this should be possible. Let me tinker that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XSD will allow any combination of `a` and `b` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="a" type="ab"/>
  <xs:element name="b" type="ab"/>

  <xs:complexType name="ab">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="a"/>
      <xs:element ref="b"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

### With Attributes

Update per OP edit of original question:

> Update: Added attributes to 'b' node.

To specify that an attribute, `attr1`, must appear on `a` and `b`, add an `xs:attribute` declaration within `xs:complexType` as usual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="a" type="ab"/>
  <xs:element name="b" type="ab"/>

  <xs:complexType name="ab">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="a"/>
      <xs:element ref="b"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="attr1" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

To specify that an attribute, `attr1`, must appear on `b` without also requiring it on `a`, do as above but split the definitions for `a` and `b`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="a" type="aType"/>
  <xs:element name="b" type="bType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="aType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="a"/>
      <xs:element ref="b"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="bType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="a"/>
      <xs:element ref="b"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="attr1" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Need to investigate *why*, but yours is working and mine not! (even after trying to quick fix it) The fame is yours! ;)

Comment: Fantastic. But one more question. If elements 'a', 'b' takes certain attributes, this is failing. Where can I specify 'use="required" ' for attributes of 'a' or 'b'. Using <xs:complexType> is throwing an error